# Writing to output file

Tags: c++

Are there any problems with this?  This part of the code is the same type of format as the other options that work but this one isn't writing to the output file.

```
else if (choice1 == 4) {
  int nodes[100];
  int b = 0;
  int number;

  cout << "Please give the nodes that you want to include in the sub-graph.\n"
       << "(press -1 to stop input): ";

  do {
    cin >> number;
    nodes[b++] = number;
    b++;
  } while (number != (-1));

  outfile.open("output.txt", ::ofstream::in | ::ofstream::out | ::ofstream::app);

  if (outfile.is_open()) {
    outfile << "nodes[0]" << nodes[1] << nodes[2];
  }

  cout << endl << "Report stored in file: output.txt." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is it even opening the file?  Seems you need to add some more error checking.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
do {
  cin >> number;
  nodes[b++] = number;
  b++;
} while (number != (-1));
```

I see couple of problems with the code in this `do-while` loop.

1. You are storing the number -1 in `nodes`. From what I understood, -1 is a signal to stop. It doesn't make sense to store it.
2. You are incrementing `b` twice in the loop. Maybe that's your intention, maybe it is an error of oversight.

The above block of code can be changed to:

```
while (true)
{
  cin >> number;
  if ( number == -1 )
  {
    break;
  }
  nodes[b++] = number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everything is correct, but you're missing something. In order for the changes to take effect you want to close the file properly.

Use `outfile.close();`

```
else if(choice1==4) 
{
    int nodes[100];
    int b=0;
    int number;
    cout<< "Please give the nodes that you want to include in the sub-graph.\n (press -1 to stop input): ";

    do
    {
        cin>>number;
        nodes[b++]=number;
        b++;
    }
    while(number!= (-1));

    outfile.open ("output.txt", ::ofstream::in | ::ofstream::out | ::ofstream::app);
    if (outfile.is_open())
    {
        outfile<<"nodes[0]"<<nodes[1]<<nodes[2];
    }
    outfile.close();
    cout<<endl<<"Report stored in file: output.txt."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `fstream`s close automatically when they go out of scope / are destroyed.

Comment: @user657267 Maybe, maybe not. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/ :P

Comment: No, it is guaranteed by the standard.